# How to specify domain controller with realm command for joining active directory?

Tags: 20.04, active-directory

While joining Ubuntu 20.04 machine to AD domain using `realm` command, I want to specify the local domain controller, is this possible?

```
realm -v join ad-domain.com -u administrator -dc dc1.ad-domain.com
```

Ubuntu machines have network connectivity to local domain controllers only and realm by default randomly chooses the domain controllers to talk to, so it keeps on failing and I have to keep on retrying the command until it stumbles upon local domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the AD domain name with the domain controller name or IP

```
realm -v join -u administrator <domain controller>
```